# MVC Controller Index sometimes 404?

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc

I've added 3 controllers, and for one of them the Index view doesn't work by default.

```
Works(shows index):
http://localhost:1767/Employees/  
http://localhost:1767/Employees/Index
http://localhost:1767/Home/       
http://localhost:1767/Home/Index
http://localhost:1767/
http://localhost:1767/Companies/Index

Doesn't work(gives 404 error):
http://localhost:1767/Companies/
```

1) I created an entity framework class library, generated from a database containing a Employees and Companies table.

2) Created a MVC 3 empty project.

3)Added a project reference from the MVC project to the EF class library project.

4)Added a controller, and in the add controller dialog I chose the EF model and one of the tables and named the controller CompaniesController

5)Then I remembered I needed a HomeController, so I added another controller, naming it HomeController, and again chose the Companies entity.

6)Finally I added a EmployeesController choosing the Employees entity.

This is the only route in my Global.asax.cs:

```
routes.MapRoute(
          "Default", // Route name
          "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
          new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
```

Why doesn't the http://localhost:1767/Companies/ URL default to the index action like all of the other controllers?  I have done a few practice MVC projects and seem to always have this problem.  The Employees controller defaulting to Index works fine, even though there is no route that tells it to do this?

Edit: Here is the error I receive:

```
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Companies/
```

Edit: So I usually don't reveal the names of my entities or domain details when posting examples online, but in this case Companies was really called Properties, and changing the name to Properties2 for the view folder and controller fixed the issue.  So it seems Properties is a special keyword that breaks the default to Index if it appears in a URL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changed the view folder and controller from Properties(Controller) to Properties2(Controller) and it works fine now.  Apperently "Properties" has some special handling in a URL and breaks the defaulting to index

Comment: I think it might be because properties is standard folder holding AssemblyInfo.cs (project template). It should have been 4XX error message not sure why you received 404 though.

Comment: Bingo... had EXACTLY this problem.

Comment: D'oh. I had a Views/Views folder and a ViewsController. It worked if you typed in Views/Index as part of the URL but not Views alone. Changed to MapViews and all is well. Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 3):

Did you add an Index action to your CompaniesController?

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Also, make sure that you have a Index.cshtml or Index.aspx (whatever view engine you are using) into the Views/Companies folder

Comment: Yes.  I have been just letting the Add Controller dialog do all of that scaffolding for me, but I did verify there is a `public ViewResult Index()`

Answer (score 3):

I received 403.1 because I had folder name same as controller name under web project root directory. So even before it reaches MVC route resolution, it fails trying to list folder content. May be similar issue with properties being standard folder in any project

Comment: I had the 404 as described but this was the issue - I have a controller called DevelopmentController.cs, and also had a directory called Development. Changed the directory name to Dev, happy days!

Answer (score 2):

Have you got a Index view in your Views folders under Companies?  i.e. Views/Companies/Index.aspx?

The only reason I would see it not working (based on the info provided) was because of spelling mistake, the Companies controller is not inheriting from controller or implementing the IController interface, or the view is missing from the Views/Controller folder for the action Index.

Edited:  This is what I would expect the CompaniesController to look like:

```
namespace MyProject.Controllers

public class CompaniesController : Controller
{
     [HttpGet]
     public ActionResult Index() {
         return View();
     }
}
```

And it would reside in the Controllers folder of your project.

Comment: Yes there is a Index.cshtml, I let the Add Controller dialog do all of the scaffolding for me, so I don't know how it would have gotten the other actions right but mispelled the Index

Comment: Are you able to post the summary of the error that comes up i.e. does it say something like unable to locate Index view.  Folders searched are Views/Index, Views/Shared, .... etc

Comment: I have edited the post with the error message.  It is just the regular 404 error that MVC uses.

Comment: Just to verify.  your controller (file and class) is called CompaniesController not CompaniesControllerController.  That's something I did once and took me a while to find it.

Comment: Yep, the name of the class in the code file, and the name of the file are both CompaniesController

Comment: The error I would think relates to the controller and/or action not being found.  However based on what you have said this seems all in place.

Comment: @AaronLS let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1431/discussion-between-dreza-and-aaronls)